# Odds of an event happening

Tags: permutations, combinations

Trying to get my head around the correct way of approach this.

You are able to use any letter of the alphabet or number allowing for 36 options, with this you are to create PIN of length 4, for example ZJA4. What are the chances of someone guessing 2 characters of your PIN?

For this I was using the permutation formula, in the above it would mean there was 1296 permutations however does this mean there is a 1 in 1296 chance of guessing correctly? I assume the other two digits dont actually matter in this example because you are only being asked to guess two of them. Also how do these odds chance if you had to guess 3 characters?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly two or at least two?  If the former:  each guess has a $\frac 1{36}$ chance of success, so $\binom 42\times \left( \frac 1{36}\right)^2\times\left( \frac {35}{36}\right)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is $\frac{{4\choose2}35^2}{36^4}$.  The two correct digits could be any two of the four positions ${4\choose2}$ and the number of ways the rest of the digits not correctly guessed is $35^2$ and the total ways is $36^4$

I hope I understood the problem correctly.

Comment: Hi, positions would be fixed so you would be asked to guess positions 1 and 3 (for example)

Comment: remove ${4\choose2}$

Comment: ok so that does simplify to a 1 in 1296 chance? could you explain how you got to that formula?

Comment: The first and the third digits are indeed guessed correctly. The number of ways they could be the correct digits are 1.  The second digit is incorrectly guessed and they could from the other 35 characters.  Similarly the fourth digits could be from the other 35 characters. Thus the numerator is 1.35.35. Also the denominator is 36^4 because each digist could be from 36 characters and multiply.  This is how I churned the formula out.